# zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available in Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, zlib

I have two python versions, two different places 2.6 and 2.7, as shown below

```
#python --version
Python 2.6.6
#/usr/local/python27/bin/python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.15
```

I need to install paramiko module, which doesn't exists, So trying to install through pip, pip its self prompting below error

```
# pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in <module>
    class Environment:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 963, in Environment
    self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 190, in get_supported_platform
    plat = get_build_platform()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 393, in get_build_platform
    from sysconfig import get_platform
ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

So I install get-pip.py and trying to configure as below , though I have installed zlib

```
# ./python2.7 get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 21401, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

Since my python2.7 custom installation, again I tried on configure with  LDFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=/usr/include/"  where the zlib library located at /usr/include/ though still I am getting the "zipimport.ZipImportError:" error, your help much appreciated.

```
./configure --enable-shared \
        --prefix=/usr/local/python27  \
        LDFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=/usr/include/"
```